# Why am i getting an extra line at the beginning of output?

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    string s,e;
    cin>>n;
    vector <pair<string,string>> m(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> s >> e;
        if (e.find("gmail")!=string::npos)
            m[i]=make_pair(s,e);
    }

    sort(m.begin(),m.end());
    auto it=m.begin();
    while(it!=m.end())
    {
        cout<<it->first<<"\n";
        it++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
julia
julia
riya
samantha
tanya
```

My output is correct, but one extra line is getting printed at the beginning and hence none of my test cases pass in Hackerrank.

Comment: Also please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) As well as about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). For example, what is the input? What is the *expected* output?

Comment: Also, please make use of the preview function and format your post (and the code within) properly. However, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: What is your *input*? and are you aware that you're incrementing `i` in your input loop even when you're rejecting the input?

Comment: Thanks to all,I got the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a vector of size `n`. Then you check for each input line if the second string contains the text `gmail` and you store the pair in the `i`-th element. You increment `i` even if you skip the input. That means that some elements of the vector can remain empty. At the end you print all elements.

E.g. input is:

```
7
julia gmil
julia gmail
julia gmail
riya gmail
samantha gmail
samantha gmil
tanya gmail
```

You store:

```
m[0]:
m[1]: julia
m[2]: julia
m[3]: riya
m[4]: samantha
m[5]:
m[6]: tanya
```

The output after sort is

```
(empty)
(empty)
julia
julia
riya
samantha
tanya
```